# How to configure Eclipse WTP deployment?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

When I click 'run' on the server in my WTP Dynamic web project, there seems to be a default configuration regarding what my `WebApp-root` is, where java files are put, etc. How can I customize that?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell about the frameworks(modules) you are trying to use. I expect you are starting with Servlets/JSP. Pls refer the tutorial. Try this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html

Comment: I mean, where do I configure where files from my sources are placed in my war?

Comment: @GerritLober use build path option in eclipse. Just right click for that on any folder.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no definition unless src/main/resource folder. There is defined /target/classes as default folder. Why WTP knows to copy this to /WEB-INF/classes/?